# How to execute a function on an object if and only if it implements a certain trait in rust?

Tags: rust

I would like to execute a function if and only if an object implements a certain trait in rust.

For example, I want to provide an algorithm that takes an input which has to implement a certain trait so that my algorithm works.  I do not want to impose further requirements to use my algorithm.  My algorithm performs some logging and I would like it to log the values of the objects it works with *if it implements `Debug`*.  If it does not do so, I want to log in a 'generic way'.

Consider the function

```rust
trait Valuable {
  fn get_value(&self) -> i32;
}

fn add<T: Valuable>(a: &T, b: &T) -> i32 {
  a.get_value() + b.get_value()
}
```

I would love to do something like

```
fn add<T: Valuable>(a: &T, b: &T) -> i32 {
  if T: Debug {
    println!("{:?} + {:?}", a, b);
  } else {
    println!("adding to valuables");
  }
  a.get_value() + b.get_value()
}
```

and I *do not* want to impose that `add` can only be used with `Valuable + Debug`.

I suppose that there is a clever trick/macro/meta programming technique to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you match a trait in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051433/how-do-you-match-a-trait-in-rust)

Comment: Related: [println!() only if object implements Debug trait](/q/64513891/2189130)

Answer (score 3):

This is called [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html) and is not supported by current Rust.

If you agree to make your function a macro, then you can have some limited support in the name of [autoref specialization](https://github.com/dtolnay/case-studies/tree/master/autoref-specialization).